# How to make "Previous Page" go to the permalink of the previous post on Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr, permalinks

On Tumblr, I'm trying to set up a webcomic format for my theme.

I have it set so that you see 1 post per page. When you hit the front page, you should see the most recent post and then the "Previous Post" button. I want this button to link to the permalink of the previous post, not the next page of the blog.

I know that within a post, you can navigate to the previous/next posts with this block:

```
{block:PermalinkPagination}
{block:NextPost}<a href="{NextPost}">Next</a>{/block:NextPost}
{block:PreviousPost}<a href="{PreviousPost}">Previous</a>{/block:PreviousPost}
{/block:PermalinkPagination}<p>
```

Is there any way to get this to work on the front page?

Answer (score 1):

In case you didn't find the solution yet, here's how to do what you want.

First way:
Set 'post per page' to 1 in "customize theme > Advanced" page. You can show all things like notes, tags etc on the front page (Index Page) like you do on permalink page, if it's what you need.

```
{block:Pagination}

{block:PreviousPage}
<a title="Newer" href="{PreviousPage}">Newer</a>
{/block:PreviousPage}

{block:NextPage}
<a title="Older" href="{NextPage}">Older</a>                     
{/block:NextPage}

{/block:Pagination}
```

Second way (With the codes you're trying to do):
Put the cover of your comic, little about the comic, plus your imagination on the first page within blocks;

```
{block:IndexPage} YOUR DESIGNS {/block:IndexPage}
```

and all your 'posts' within blocks;

```
{block:PermalinkPage} YOUR POST {/block:PermalinkPage}
```

Put a link to first page (most recent post's permalink page) of your comic, 
and then you can use your code for next and previous posts to your comic.

```
{block:PermalinkPagination}

{block:NextPost}
<a title="Newer" href="{NextPost}">Newer</a>                     
{/block:NextPost}

{block:PreviousPost}
<a title="Older" href="{PreviousPost}">Older</a>
{/block:PreviousPost}

{/block:PermalinkPagination}
```

This last code won't work on the front (Index Page) 'cause it's for pagination on permalink pages.
Notice, the block says: "Permalink Pagination".

Hope it helps, best wishes with your comics.

Comment: Hi @ialok, I don't quite understand this answer. I am also looking for a solution for this. Do you mean that the index page should have a link to the most recent post that you are constantly updating with each new post? Is there a way to just show the post and have pagination work by permalink instead of page number?